# Does a remote system accessed with SSH have a system clipboard?

Tags: ssh, clipboard, copy-paste

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) in the `bash` shell `control+u`

> Clears the line content before the cursor and copies it into the clipboard

If I'm ssh'ed into a box and try that, the text certainly disappears but I have no idea where it goes. Can I access it somehow? I don't want to have to use `xsel` or set up `x-forwarding`, I am just curious if it is stored in some register somewhere remotely. For example, I tried starting `vim` and typing `"*p` or `"+p` to paste from the system clibpoard but am not having any luck.

If I use `control+u` remotely when ssh'ed to a box, where does it go, and can I access it?

Comment: I *think* that x-forwarding (which is really just as simple as adding `-X` to your SSH options) should enable "*y in vim, if vim on the server has X-clipboard support built in. Otherwise, no, there's no shared clipboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can yank (paste) it back somewhere with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> as in emacs.

See the "Killing and Yanking" subsection of bash manual "Readline" section.

Comment: Yes, this is bash's internal clipboard, completely confined to that remote invocation of bash. (There's no notion of an interprocess clipboard in the shell environment; normally X provides this.)